# Function to get elevation stats for observations

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am working with observations of different species and I am interested in the topography of the surrounding environment.
I have a FeatureCollection with many observations and I would like to `.map()` a function over the FeatureCollection to get the values for each observation.

For now I have come up with this:

```
def get_elevation_stats(point, image = elevation):
    
    # Selecting the area in 1km radius around the point
    pt = point.setGeometry(point.geometry().buffer(1000)))

    # Getting the mean elevation as well as the Max and Min elevation in 1km around the point
    pt = elevation.reduceRegion(
        reducer = ee.Reducer.mean().combine(
            reducer2 = ee.Reducer.minMax(), sharedInputs = True
        ),
        geometry = pt.geometry()
    )

    # Return the input with the additional factors
    return point.set({
        'elevation_diff': point.getNumber('max').subtract(point.getNumber('min')), 
        'mean_elevation': point.getNumber('mean')
        }
    )
```

The code is not too complicated, however I am having issues running it. Do you see any errors?

Comment: thanks for asking! Madeleine understood my not so clear idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is just a little clumsy and has small errors:

- Don't use the same variable name for the outputs of reduceRegion and
  your buffered point regions, otherwise pt.geometry() fails since the
  output of reduceRegion is numeric (no geometry available)
- You need to define a geometry when using reduceRegion, in this case
  pt.geometry()
- When setting the properties of your end result, the number is likely
  not named 'max', 'min' and 'mean' but instead 'elevation_max',
  'elevation_min' etc. (or whatever the band is named)

In GEE your function would look like this (it just needs to be adjusted for Python):

```
function get_elevation_stats(point){
  var pt = point.setGeometry(point.geometry().buffer(1000))
  var ptElev = elevation.reduceRegion({
    geometry: pt.geometry(),
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
    .combine({
      reducer2: ee.Reducer.minMax(), 
      sharedInputs: true
    })
  });
  var geometry = pt.geometry();
  return point.set({
    'elevation_diff': ptElev.getNumber('elevation_max')
      .subtract(ptElev.getNumber('elevation_min')), 
    'mean_elevation': ptElev.getNumber('elevation_mean')
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!!